# Why does thumbnail on one MXD not update?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, thumbnail

I want to make modification on multi-mxd properties, I try Arcpy script with a loop like " for mxd in mxdList:" , but I always have same results, Thumbnails are not created...

```
import arcpy,os
dossierRech = "C:\TEMP"
arcpy.env.workspace = dossierRech
mxdList = arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd")
for mxd in mxdList:
    filePath = os.path.join(dossierRech, file)
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(filePath)
    mxd.deleteThumbnail()
    mxd.makeThumbnail()
    mxd.save()
```

I try on only one MXD , it doesn't created it too.

Is there some issue with "mxd.makeThumbnail()" ?

Comment: At the moment I think you are showing us more code than we need to see in order to work on your underlying question which is "Why does thumbnail on one MXD not update?"  I think you should reduce what you have to a code snippet that illustrates just that.  To get it working on multiple MXDs you'll need to make sure that it works on one first.

Comment: Ok, I change it

Comment: I think that you have over-pruned your code snippet.  What I was looking for was one that started with `import arcpy` and then works with just one mxd to try and delete then create its thumbnail.  In the meantime I ran some quick tests and the deletion/creation of thumbnails from ArcPy seems unreliable to me too.

Comment: I begin in python script, so i found another idea, do you think my issue is due to the loop ? I saw this link, and they use OS... http://mappingcenter.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=ask.answers&q=1504

Comment: At that link `os` is only being used to deal with pathnames.  I notice that you are using a Python script tool which makes your code longer than may be necessary.  As a test I think you should set `arcpy.env.workspace` to a full pathname to take your tool dialog parameters out of the equation.

Comment: it's because i cut my first script ! I use it for apply different properties parameters to multi-mxd (in an Atlas), it works well only for Thumbnails...

Comment: My advice above is about trying to determine why thumbnails on map documents are *seeming* to be difficult to overwrite reliably from ArcPy.  Once that is resolved then it should be much easier to ask about any remaining issues in your script/tool.

Comment: Ok, I understand, try this one...but thumbnail doesn't change on my computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To try and help with this I have run some tests but they are providing an unexpected result so I think you should report this to your local Esri support.

First I wrote a simple script which should open an MXD, make its thumbnail and save the MXD with that thumbnail.  On any subsequent runs the script should overwrite the existing thumbnail with a new one.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\temp\test.mxd")
mxd.makeThumbnail()
mxd.save()
```

I then authored C:\temp\test.mxd to have a single layer in a single symbol.

Then my steps were:

1. With ArcMap closed run the script from IDLE
2. Close both IDLE windows (to prevent any chance of file locking between the applications) and open ArcMap to a blank map.
3. In the Catalog window go to C:\temp and see that the thumbnail has been created as expected
4. Open C:\temp\test.mxd and change the symbology on that layer to a unique value classification (or anything that makes the map look very different).
5. Save the map and close ArcMap
6. Run the script from IDLE
7. Close both IDLE windows (to prevent any chance of file locking between the applications) and open ArcMap to a blank map.
8. In the Catalog window go to C:\temp and see that the thumbnail has not been overwritten as expected and instead no longer exists!

I think this is a bug in the `makeThumbnail` method of the Map Document object.

---

As [commented by the asker](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133399/why-does-thumbnail-on-one-mxd-not-update#comment198103_135754):

> BUG-000085788: Map document thumbnail fails to generate if using
>   .deleteThumbnail() and then makeThumbnail() after second run.
>   Unfortunately the BUG is present on 10.3 as well.